# Nonhomogeneous PDE for the 2-dimensional heat flow

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the BVP for the two-dimensional heat flow (the pde is nonhomogeneous) in a square plate. The side $x=20$ is insulated while the other sides are kept at 0 temperature. There is a heat source $F(x,y,t)$.

$u_t = u_{xx} + u_{yy} + F(x,y,t),$          $0 < x < 20$, $0 < y < 20$, $t > 0$

$u(0,y,t) = u_x(20,y,t)=0,$              $0 < y < 20$, $t > 0$

$u(x,0,t) = u(x,20,t)=0,$                $0 < x < 20$, $t > 0$

$u(x,y,0)=0$                            $0 < x < 20$, $0 < y < 20$

We take $F(x,y,t)=f(x,y)\cos(t)$

with $ f(x,y)= 100 $ if $9 < x < 11$, $9 < y < 11$.

Comment: What is value of $f(x,y)$ on the rest of the rectangle?

Comment: 0 is the value for the rest of the rectangle

Comment: As a curiosity, in which book did you find this problem?

Comment: Can I know where you find this problem?

Comment: This is a lab question my professor developed.